# PhpStorm 2017 autopopup completion not working outside <> symbols

Tags: tab-completion, phpstorm

If I type `<` symbol and then continue typing, autopopup completion works just as intended:
[image]

But outside of `<>` tags(either html or php - `<a></a>` or `<?php  ?>`, for example) autopopup completion doesn't work:

[image]

In the above example I can still press `TAB` and it will complete code based on the first code snippet in the list, because it sees all the options, it just doesn't show them to me.

In the case above, in order to show completion options I have to press `CTRL+Space` after I type `p`, for example, and then it starts to show completion options:
[image]

My settings:
[image]

Is this a bug? Or what? Why autopopup completion doesn't work outside of `<>`? Is there a way to make autopopup completion to always work?

If there is no official way to do it, maybe there is a way to automatically trigger `Main Menu | Code | Completion | Basic` command - as if I press `CTRL+Space` whenever any character is typed into the editor?

Comment: when you enter `<`, PHPStorm knows that the tag is expected and auto-popups the completion. But PHP/HTML files can contain plain text and the IDE can't know what you are going to type. Showing auto-completion on entering text would be rather annoying, so only explicit completion (on `Ctrl+Enter`) is shown unless you are editing a tag/php code fragment

Comment: similar thread: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000719050-Autopopup-completion-works-inside-php-tag-but-doesn-t-work-outside-of-it-Is-there-any-fix-